# What should I not include in the `included do ... end` block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, activesupport

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. I am implementing a module and including that in a my class by using the RoR [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) feature. It makes available the `included do ... end` block making code stated inside that to be executed in the class context of the class where the module is included.

My doubt is: *What should I **not** include in the `included do ... end` block?* That is, for instance, is it a "common" / "good" practice to make the following?

```
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class MyModuleClass
    attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2, :attr3

    def initialize(attrs)
     @attr1 = attrs[:attr1]
     @attr2 = attrs[:attr2]
     @attr3 = attrs[:attr3]
    end
  end

  included do
    @my_module_class = MyModuleClass.new(some_attrs)
  end
end
```

*More*, will be the `@my_module_class` variable available as an attribute in the including class of `MyModule` (*BTW*: I would like to make the `@my_module_class` to be "visible" *only* internally to `MyModule` since it is intended to be used only in that module)? Are there some "advanced" examples or tutorials on how to handle situations like that I am trying to instantiate in the `included do ... end` block of the above code? What do you advice about?

Answer (score 2):

@my_class will be an instance of MyClass and not MyModule.  If you want to make all instances of MyClass be an instance of MyModule you should write:

```
 include MyModule
```

inside the class definition.

I think my answer makes sense if you look at the original version of this question before it was edited.

**EDIT 1:**

Let's add on to your example and say you have a class called Foo:

```
class Foo
    include MyModule
end
```

You want to make an instance of MyModuleClass that is associated with Foo but it sounds like you don't really want to modify Foo or give it access to the MyModuleClass.  I propose that you use a hash table:

```
module MyModule
    # ...

    @hash = {}
    class << self
        attr_accessor :hash
    end

    included do
        MyModule.hash[self] = MyModuleClass.new(some_attrs)
    end
end
```

I think that will work, and it avoids adding an instance variable to to the `Foo` class object.  Technically, any part of the ruby code can access MyModule.hash but you should put a comment in the source code telling people NOT to do that, and don't advertise that the hash exists.

Comment: Thank you, but the "main" question is related to "What should I *not* include in the `included do ... end` block?" relating, *for example*, to my case. The rest is a "more", even if it is very important to me. However, I do *not* want to make all instances of `MyModuleClass` be an instance of `MyModule`, but to make those available only internally to `MyModule`; furthermore, the `include MyModule` statement inside the class definition is implicit / obvious, since the module is intended to be included in a class.

Comment: The question of "what should I not do" is too vague for me to really answer, but please see my "Edit 1" above where I attempt to solve the problem you are asking about.